# Populate data in DropDown box using sapui5

Tags: json, sapui5

```
var oItemsData = {
          items: [
            {"key" : "City1", "text" : "India"}, 
            {"key" : "City2", "text" : "America"}, 
            {"key" : "City3", "text" : "Germany"}, 
            {"key" : "City4", "text" : "France"}
          ]
        };

var oItemsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oItemsData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oItemsModel, "items");
new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"FirstOne"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({value:"",required: true,
                        items: { 
                            path: "items>/items",
                            template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                              text: { path: "items>text" }//how to filter
                            }) 
                          }
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.commons.Label({text:"SecondOne"}),
                    new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({value:"",required: true,
                        items: { 
                            //populate on the basis of 1st one's input
                            }) 
                          }
                    })
```

This is working fine with the above json data.

But I faced problem when my json data looks like below :

```
{
  "CountryList" : [
      {
        "key" : "City1", "text" : "India"
      }, {
        "key" : "City2", "text" : "America"
      }, {
        "key" : "City3", "text" : "Germany"
      }, {
        "key" : "City4", "text" : "France"
      }
  ]
}
```

I attempted this below code :

```
var oItemsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oItemsModel.loadData("json/countryList.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oItemsModel, "CountryList");

new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("Cities", {
                selectedItemId : "{CountryList>/CountryList/0/callingfrom}", 
                items: {        
                  path: "items>/CountryList",
                  template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                    key: {path: "items>key"},
                    text: {path: "items>text"}
                  }) 
                },
              })
```

But not working.

How to build data in dropdown box when Json format like above.

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing here but all you have done is change the aggregation name from "items" to "CountryList"

therefore try referencing the new name

```
new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({value:"",required: true,
   items: { 
          path: "items>/CountryList",  // >> here
          template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
          text: { path: "items>text" }//how to filter
       }) 
   }
}),
```

Comment: I pasted my json data in one json file. And then load data from JSON file. Thats why I am facing the issue.

Comment: What John means is you should change the named model prefix `items>` to `CountryList>` (since you apparently renamed it as such in the model instantiation)

Answer (score 0):

Solution of the above problem :

```
var oItemsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oItemsModel.loadData("json/countryList.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oItemsModel, "CountryList");

new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("Cities", {
            selectedItemId : "{CountryList>/CountryList/0/callingfrom}", 
           items: {        
                  path: "CountryList>/CountryList",
                  template: new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                    key: {path: "CountryList>key"},
                    text: {path: "CountryList>text"}
                  }) 
                },
              })
```